# Swap Control and CapsLock with use of loadkeys in text console

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, console

I wish to swap Control with Caps Lock but in text console (not terminal emulator on X11/Wayland). I gone through manual pages of loadkeys and keymaps. After few tries I did it but do not fully understand the solution.

I used loadkeys as follows:

```
sudo loadkeys <filename>
```

where the  content was:

```
keycode 58 = Control
keycode 29 = Caps_Lock
```

then I've checked result with dumpkeys which shows:

```
keycode  58 = Control          CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock       CtrlL_Lock      
keycode  29 = Caps_Lock        Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control          Control
```

It wasn't what I expected to get and caused keyboard to be unusable after CapsLock was pressed.

Then I added *keymap* as keymaps manual suggested. Then the map file looked like:

```
keymaps 0-6,8-9,12
keycode 58 = Control
keycode 29 = Caps_Lock
```

and dumpkeys shows:

```
keycode  29 = Caps_Lock       
keycode  58 = Control
```

Now it works as I wanted. The questions now are:

1. Why in the first case the very first column has been populated with value from my map file but rest of 256 got some values? Why 'CtrlL_Lock' for 58 and why 'Control' for 29?
2. In second case only very first value was populated and rest are blank when *keymap* in fact defines more than one column?